# BlackBerry - TreeField with radiobutton

Tags: blackberry, treeview, radio-button, treefield

Is it possible to add radiobutton to a TreeField in Blackberry ?

Comment: You should do some research before asking a general question like this.  Performing a simple Google search with your question "add radiobutton to a TreeField in Blackberry" provides your answer.

Comment: I figured out the problem as soon as possible to share with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add buttons to a TreeField in BlackBerry. Instead you can write some lines of code to create a collapsible Manager that will delete the fields when you click on a button:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-add-radiobuttongroup-to-treefield/m-p/1278907/highlight/true#M171881